# Issue with nslookup on virtual machine

Tags: vmware-esxi, nslookup

I have a Unitrends backup virtual machine running as a virtual machine. I also have a Windows Server running as a virtual machine. I can ping anything on the network from the Windows virtual machine. I can ping the windows virtual machine from physical machines on the network. The issue is when using name lookup on the Unitrends backup machine the Unitrends cannot see the Windows server to back it up.

Our IP addresses are dynamic and I need to use name lookup rather than a hard coded IP address in Unitrends. Unitrends is using nslookup to get IP addresses. When I log in SSH to Unitrends and run nslookup I do not get an IP address for my Windows server by name. I DO have the correct DNS servers configured. Using nslookup on the Unitrends does return the correct IP addresses for other machines, just not the Windows server virtual machine.

I have turned off the firewall on the Windows server and on the Unitrends backup server - didn't help. Other Windows 7 computers on the physical network cannot see either virtual machine when using "Network".

Not sure what the issue is but feels like a setting in EXSi. Any help troubleshooting this would be appreciated.

Some answers to specific questions:
NIC is on same network as other hosts.
DNS configuration matches the configuration that works for physical computers on the same network
Unitrends and the Windows server both have IP's on the same network.

What I get when I do a nslookup from the Unitrends for the Windows server:

```
[root@VMware-UB ~]# nslookup
eng-winsvr
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 192.168.69.10, trying next server
Server:         192.168.69.8
Address:        192.168.69.8#53

** server can't find eng-winsvr: SERVFAIL
```

Comment: `When I log in SSH to Unitrends and run nslookup I do not get an IP address for my Windows server by name` - `Using nslookup on the Unitrends does return the correct IP addresses for other machines, just not the Windows server virtual machine.` - These two statements contradict each other. Please clarify.

Comment: No, they don't contradict each other. I am saying that from Unitrends using nslookup I cannot get the IP for the Windows server. I CAN get the IP for all the other physical machines on that network. I am saying that nslookup itself works - the only case it does not is when trying to get the IP for the Windows virtual server. I could have been clearer though.

Comment: OK. I misread your question. It looked like you stated that you could and couldn't resolve the Windows server name with nslookup on the Uitrends machine.

Comment: Is the NIC configured on the same network as the other hosts? Does your DNS server configuration in unitrends match that of other hosts on the network? Does it haven an IP in the same subnet? There's not enough information here to really help narrow this down. `When I log in SSH to Unitrends and run nslookup I do not get an IP address for my Windows server by name` what do you get instead? What do other machines gen when using `nslookup`?

Comment: Added answers to questions above in original post.

Comment: `1.` You're submitting an unqualified, single-label name query to nslookup. Is the Unitrends machine configured to use/append a DNS suffix? `2.` Your primary DNS server isn't responding. Does the secondary DNS server have a copy of the same DNS zones as the primary DNS server?